# How to find and get rid of docker residual data?

Tags: docker

I am running docker on windows and even though I do `docker system prune` it is using more and more space somewhere on my harddisk.

Often after restarting the laptop and running prune I can get rid of some more but its less than it actually takes.

I know that docker is using these space because space on my HDD decreases when building new images and running containers but always decreases by much less space.

It's eaten over 50gb of my 256 gb SSD.

I appreciate any help in how to find and efficiently locate all files docker leaves when building and running containers.

I tried many lines from here and most work but I always fail to reclaim all space and given that I have a very small SSD I really need all the space I can get back.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably WSL. You can try to shrink WSL partitions with diskpart https://superuser.com/questions/1606213/how-do-i-get-back-unused-disk-space-from-ubuntu-on-wsl2

Comment: You could also check with something like https://www.diskanalyzer.com/

Comment: @andreoss thank you so much, I reinstalled wsl and I somehow removed 40+ gb of allocation that docker has created in the past 2 days. 
wsl --shutdown alone got rid of nearly 10 gb. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add to the command `docker system prune` the `--all' because of:

```
-a, --all : Remove all unused images not just dangling ones
```

I use this to free up all my no more needed disk space.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using `-a` and pretty much all. Alone from docker it didn't help. Andreoss seems to be correct after I check wsl allocation. Thanks for the input though.